# how to write a tcp proxy?

Tags: tcp, proxy

I am  curious  about  the **tcp proxy implementation**.

Can you give me some **tips** about how to understand and develop  a  naive version?

And is there any good **materials(or open projects)** or **tutorial** on it?  =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building a well working proxy is no simple task as you will have to understand and handle several protocols etc. in both directions...

I would recommend to either use an existing library for that OR some configurable proxy...

- http://www.mentalis.org/soft/projects/proxy/ (with source)
- http://fusion.corsis.eu/ (with source)
- http://www.wingate.com/
- http://www.squid-cache.org/

Comment: @Yahia This is the first time I spot someone mentioning PortFusion, as its developer, by pure chance. :) Thank you for mentioning it in proper context.