# Packet sniffing and modification

Tags: c#, packet, winpcap

First, why do I need that? I have Wifi network. I want everyone that just connected to wifi first to redirect to login page and then if login is successful - redirect to the page requested. I thought to do that using PCap. But since WinPCap allows just to monitor packets, I can't stop packet from being sent to destination host. So the question is how can I sniff packet and change it content? As of beginning i want to capture HTTP packets only from specified network adapter.

Comment: Most routers will have a built in mechanism for authentication.  Why are you trying to do all of this manually?

Comment: because I want to control authorization process on my server, not router.

Comment: Your question and intent do not match. Your intent seem to be "how to implement gateway/proxy" but question is "how to modify network packets". You need either to learn more about TCP routing OR change the reason in the question.

Comment: Yes, I need a kind of proxy, but i want to redirect to that proxy packets, which come from wifi adapter. Is that possible without client machines configuration?

Answer (score 2):

That's really hard to do the way you describe - doing this on "packet level" will present several problems (among others performance!).

To achieve what you want you have several easier and better suited options:

- use a proxy which handles the autentication part
- build a proxy (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8113066/847363) for C# source code etc.)

For the proxy-based options you just need to configure the network in a way that all outbound traffic must use that proxy...