# Control the browser through c# or some other way

Tags: c#, plugins, browser, firebreath

Okay I know c# got a vast and very ease to use application development programs but this is what i want to learn now.So when user opens his browser and enters some url in it. Is it possible to send this data or the entered `url address`to some other code one such a c# code or some other example c++ which is located on his hard drive.

To be simple when user clicks some link on a webpage or enters some url or closes the browser or when he opens the web browser, Can we detect all his actions that he perform on web browser through c# code or anyother way(I guess add-on or pluins the way it works) but Is it possible to send his actions to c# code and program it and give certain output back to browser so that browser performs it and outputs to user.

Something like browser-->c#code-->website.. I want c# code to act between the browser and webpages.

**work I tried so far**

I started googling on this and learnt little about how browsers work but still unable to find the solution. However I guess plugins are the way to do such tasks and found `firebreath` cross platform,a way to develop plugins for browsers. So is this possible by plugins? if so could you suggest me some good tools to develop my own plugins. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several options depending on what you want to achieve:

- Proxy

  You could implement a http proxy and configure the browser to use that proxy. The proxy sees all traffic and can do whatever it wants... this works rather "browser-agnostic". See the links [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8113066/847363) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8558384/847363).
- PlugIn

  You could implement a plugin... alhtough this a browser-specific... for example IE used to have BHOs to this kind of stuff (not sure whether this is still possible with IE10...). Some options can be found [here](http://www.culater.net/software/SIMBL/SIMBL.php), [here](http://www.enhanceie.com/ie/dev.asp), [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/350432/BHO-Development-using-managed-code), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3781180/847363) and [here](http://code.google.com/p/firebreath/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FiddlerCore](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/Core/) for this

```
Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.BeforeRequest += sess =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("REQUEST TO : " + sess.fullUrl);
    sess.bBufferResponse = true;
};

Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.Startup(8877, true, true);

Console.ReadLine();

Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.Shutdown();
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(750);
```

After running this code, open your browser and navigate to any page.